# Upload images to train ML Kit not possible

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-machine-learning

I am trying to use Firebase ML Kit in an app to label images. I want to upload training data to the dataset, but i always get the error, that my cloud bucket has to be in the region "us-central1". i am living in europe and cannot imagine that only people from this region are allowed to use this ML Kit.

Thanks very much i appreciate every suggestion.

Comment: It is not like that. When You see the region restriction it should be related to your other infra being in that region. Have you checked that ?

Comment: the error says "Cannot move files across regions. Please use a regional bucket in the same location and with same storage class as AutoML. Required Location: us-central1, required location type: Region, required storage class: Standard. " So the problem is that i have to be in the US to use the ML Kit service?

Comment: Oh i did not know that i needed to set the storage location for the Cloud bucket to that region thanks very much!